# Modifications PythonAnywhere -> GitHub

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I've made some changes directly on the code located in the PythonAnywhere files. In this way, some of them are a little bit different from the reppository GitHub files.

Assuming the PyhonAnywhere files are correct, what is the best way to 'copy' them and move to the GitHub?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your PythonAnywhere project already connected to GitHub:

1. Run Bash console on PythonAnywhere
2. Move to directory with your repository
3. Make `git push`

Comment: Good answer, but it's worth also mentioning that you need to git add and then git commit them between steps 2 and 3 if you haven't already done so.